# Electrochromic materials

Tags: materials

I have a project that involes electrochromic materials and I am wondering if it's possible for an electrochromic material to turn from white color to black and vice versa. If the answer is yes, can you name that material?

Comment: Depending on how you want to look at it, isn't this pretty much what a LCD is?

Comment: "Liquid paper" displays are another way this is achieved, although not by electrochromic property of a material.